# Framing near rough in plumbing and sump pit

Tags: plumbing, basement, framing, sump-pump

Going to be framing in a bathroom in our basement that has rough in plumbing.

How close can i frame to a sump pit?

And can framing go over a concrete drain box or do I leave a gap in the bottom plate and just have verticals on either side?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your wall plate can easily span that rough-in box. That's not a concern. What *is* maybe a concern is the location of the rough-in. Doesn't look quite right for a standard tub or shower. The builder may have expected a slightly larger room.
2. I'm not aware of any rules regarding clearance around a sump pit. You'd obviously want the lid to function properly (even after drywall and any trim) and space for any plumbing. Other than that, squeeze away. Looks like there's plenty of room to the other sides anyway.

Comment: Don’t trap the cap of the pit and it will be fine. I agree with the rough in box looking funny but if the drain is in the correct location who will know when finished.

Comment: Rough-in plumbing is setup for a 10" rough in toilet. room is like 5 x 7 more or less. Do i need to back fill the box before i install the tub?

Comment: Depends on your tub, but usually no. Dirt wouldn't help anyway--you'd need concrete.